# What's the best "React" way to create an interface to send and handle messages from postMessage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, react-hooks, react-context

I have a React app that lives in an iframe on some host site. The React app sends and receives messages via `window.postMessage` and `window.onmessage = (ev) => {/** Handle messages **/}` respectively. In my app, different components send different messages and also need to handle different types of messages. What would be the best way to implement this in React?

Would something like a custom hook or custom context be a good use case for this? If so, how?

Initial thinking was there would be a singleton class that any component could just import and use to send messages and attach callbacks to. But this doesn't feel very "React" and the class would get too big with different messages to send and callbacks to define. Appreciate any other suggestions!